# Using Model First, how do I pre-load a junction table for fast, sub-second joins?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, plinq

I want to do fast, sub-second joins across a few tables using the Entity Framework (model first).  The simplified data model is similar to the following:

*Videos*: **ID** (Primary Key); **Name**

*Tags*: **ID** (Primary Key); **Name**

*TaggedVideos*: **TagID** (FK); **VideoID** (FK)

Is there a way to pre-load *TaggedVideos* when the table is not modeled or exposed in the Entity Framework?  I'm trying to avoid database hits when searching for all videos with a certain tag.  Ideally, all three tables would be loaded into collections and I could join then using PLINQ.

If I add another column to *TaggedVideos*, I can accomplish this but I would prefer an elegant solution that doesn't clutter the data model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache the tags and make sure the have a backward nav-property to the collection of videos.

You can then access your cached version of the tag and look up the associated videos without a join.

If you dont want to cache the whole video, in your caching code select use something like Videos.Select(v=>v.Id) to select just the Ids and cache that.

Comment: When I use backward navigation on the cached tags, I get an error: *The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*  This seems like the cache is still hitting the database and the error is coming from the fact I closed the context I used to build the cache.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @james You need to do a couple of things, firstly make sure you have disconnected items (you can do this by adding .AsNoTracking() to your query see my post on this here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html) and secondly make sure your set is enumerated by using .ToArray() at the end of the query.

Comment: I'm still using EF 4.0 which doesn't support AsNoTracking.  Time to upgrade.  I give this a shot tomorrow.